# Visual Studio Code: Formatting Java method chaining

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to change the VSCode settings which will allow me to do something like this with method chaining :

```
Flux
  .just("test", "string", "flux")
  .log()
  .map(String::toUpperCase);
```

The problem is whenever the formatter is applied, it changes it back to just one line:

```
Flux.just("test", "string", "flux").log().map(String::toUpperCase);
```

I have the Java Extensions Pack installed, which includes the 'Language Support for Java by Red Hat'. That extension has a few format options added, and I've been trying to use them, but no such luck.

Here are the format options I have changed:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml",
"java.format.enabled": true,
"java.format.settings.profile": "GoogleStyle"
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can have the formatter leave multi-lined method chaining alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Redhat Developer VSCode-Java plugin wiki](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Formatter-settings):

> You can also define the formatting preferences in your project's **.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs**. It will override global formatting settings.
>   Since this is rather tedious, the best way to edit those preferences is to open your project in Eclipse and set the formatting preferences for your project there.

The option you will be looking for is:

**Line Wrapping** > **Wrapping settings** > **Function Calls** > **Qualified invocations**

Set it to **Wrap all elements, every element on a new line**, like in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did see that from the wiki, but the language "You can also define the formatting preferences..." made me think I could still find a way to just use the VS code settings.

If anyone is curious, to get it exactly how I wanted I had to choose the option above in the screenshot, but also had to choose "Force split, even if line is shorter than max..." and set the Indentation policy to "Indent by one".

Answer (score 8):

I achieved the same result without resorting to downloading Eclipse just to export the desired setting. I read the fantastic guide from [vscode-java-formatter.md](https://gist.github.com/samba2/7d2f244f4e0d2a6220ac99de570a5221)

I already have this JSON setting in vscode:

```json
"java.format.settings.url": "dir/to/eclipse-java-google-style.xml"
```

Inside the local `eclipse-java-google-style.xml`, change the following's value from `true` to `false`.

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
```

Save and restart vscode. Now chained methods won't be squeezed into one line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been looking for this for hours.